# How do I use HTML5 form elements (e.g. <input type="date">) with Elm's Style-Elements library?

Tags: html, elm

I have a view (I've mocked it up [here](https://ellie-app.com/jBDf4RMMna1/0)) which uses Elm's [style-elements](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/style-elements/4.2.1) library to generate a form:

```
formEl : Model -> E.Element MyStyles variation Msg
formEl model =
    E.column None [] <|
        [ Input.email FormField
            [ Attr.width (Attr.px 300) ]
            { onChange = FormChange
            , value = ""
            , label = Input.labelAbove <| E.text "Email"
            , options =
                [ Input.errorBelow <|
                    E.el Error [] (E.text "Fill in an email address")
                ]
            }
        , Input.text FormField
            [ Attr.width (Attr.px 300) ]
            { onChange = FormChange
            , value = ""
            , label = Input.labelAbove <| E.text "Distance"
            , options =
                [ Input.errorBelow <|
                    E.el Error [] (E.text "Fill in a distance")
                ]
            }

        -- <DATE PICKER HERE>
        ]
```

As far as I can tell, there isn't a nice way to simply set `Input.

Comment: There is a PR for adding date input. https://github.com/mdgriffith/style-elements/pull/134 I have never used style-elements by myself, but I guess it's not supported for now. Only these ones are used as the "type" for an input. https://github.com/mdgriffith/style-elements/blob/4.2.1/src/Element/Input.elm#L513-L528

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa ;) I know, I wrote that PR. Thanks for digging into it though. I'll wait on the PR but it looks like the answer for now is "you don't."